# Smooth Fonts on Windows, how do those 2 sites with Twitter Bootstrap achieve this?

Tags: css, windows, twitter-bootstrap, fonts, smoothing

On Windows 8 with Chrome the big text fonts are not smooth. However I've managed to see a few websites which has smooth texts (same environment).

First:
http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/examples/hero.html

The "Hello, world!" is smooth, however the "Heading" texts at the bottom are not smooth as you can see, even though they are smaller.

[image]

---

The other is http://www.asana.com. On their homepage the "Do Great Things" text is smooth.

[image]

---

Now both the pages are using Twitter Bootstrap CSS.

When I look at the computed style for the related html element on Chrome Developer Tools I see these values:

```
background-color: transparent;
border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
border-top-left-radius: 0px;
border-top-right-radius: 0px;
color: #333;
display: block;
font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
font-size: 60px;
font-weight: bold;
height: 60px;
letter-spacing: -1px;
line-height: 60px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
margin-left: 0px;
margin-right: 0px;
margin-top: 10px;
padding-bottom: 0px;
padding-left: 0px;
padding-right: 0px;
padding-top: 0px;
text-rendering: optimizelegibility;
width: 1050px;
```

I saw that Asana uses a font called proxima-nova-condensed, however when I used it it is not smooth for me, even with text-rendering: optimizelegibility.

Do you have any idea how do they achieve it? I'd like to learn how can I do it without Twitter Bootstrap (or with Bootstrap if I have to).

Comment: [Looks smooth to me](http://jsfiddle.net/St6FP/). I'm not sure that they're doing anything special with their fonts?

Comment: So font-size: 48px; is not smooth but font-size 50px and 60px is smooth. What the..?

Answer (score 1):

Font rendering varies. If you look close at the rendering (e.g., take a screen capture and magnify the pixels), you will see that there is just variation in smoothing. There is not much you can do about (except partly in Mac environment), so you can just test that your text looks tolerable in various platforms and browsers.